# Ruby: Parsing Nested JSON into .csv format

Tags: ruby, json, csv, parsing

I am working on a small function that takes JSON data from an API and parses it into a .csv file. Each JSON field name becomes its own column in a new .csv file. So far I haven't had any issues, but now I'm finding some nested JSON data. I'm not sure how to parse these out into their own columns.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("sample.csv", "w") do |csv| 
    csv << [ "column1",
         "column2",
         "column3"
    ]
    JSON.parse(File.open("tojson.txt").read).each do |hash| 

    csv << hash.values 


    end
end
```

Now that I have nested JSON data, I'm trying out the following code, but it's not working:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("sample.csv", "w") do |csv| 
    csv << [ "column1": 
        { [ "subcolumn1",
            "subcolumn2",
            "subcolumn3"
             ]}
         "column2",
         "column3"
    ]
    JSON.parse(File.open("tojson.txt").read).each do |hash| 

    csv << hash.values 


    end
end
```

I'm trying to get each of the subcolumns to become column headings in the CSV files. But with the code above, all I'm getting is {:column1=>"subcolumn1"} as a heading name. The heading I want to get is "subcolumn1" and I need to get all of its values.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you want two lines of headings, one line with the primary headings, and a second line with the subheadings. You can then insert blank columns in the primary headings to get them to line up when there are multiple subheadings.

Comment: Also, you can use `File.read(fileName)` instead of `File.open(fileName).read`, which technically leaves the file open. The `read` method comes from `IO`, which `File` inherits from.

Comment: @DanielStevens can you clarify what you mean by that? How would this carry over into code?

Comment: I assume this is in regards to the first comment. In which case you can write out two header lines:
`csv << ['column1', '', '', 'column2', 'column3']` and `csv << ['subcolumn1', 'subcolumn2', 'subcolumn3', '', '']`
A plain CSV file has no way to group headings and sub-headings. The best you can really do is try to align the columns.

Comment: You might also want to watch the ordering of `hash.values`. If the JSON file has optional fields, any extra or missing fields could offset your columns for any given row. You might also get out or order columns if the source data is swapped in the file. JSON can contain the fields in any order. Depending on your dataset, you might be able to ignore this problem.